# Não estou a conseguir guardar a string

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
void ex51(char *nome_ficheiro){//escrever e criar um ficheiro novo.
  char frase[100]; 
  printf("Introduza o texto que quer escrever neste ficheiro:\n"); 
  scanf("%s",frase);
  FILE *fp=fopen(nome_ficheiro,"w");
  if(fp==NULL){
      printf("Error!!!\n");
  }else{ 
      fprintf(fp,"%s",frase); 
  }
 fclose(fp);
}
```

Sempre que dou espaço ou enter ele só guarda a primeira palavra, tentei usar o gets() para resolver o problema, mas o gets() não funciona, faz com que o programa termine logo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `scanf` possui um formato para a leitura de caracteres, assim ele lê tudo o que for digitado até um valor especifico.

```
scanf("%[^\n]", var); // irá ler tudo que estiver antes do \n (quebra de linha)
```

Como sua *String* tem um tamanho fixo, pode usar uma constante para indicar o tamanho máximo que deseja ler.

```
scanf("%100[^\n], var); // irá ler os antes de \n com um limite de 100
```

Ou pode usar diretamente a leitura dos caracteres, mas não recomendo.

```
scanf("%100c", var); // lê os caracteres até um limite de 100
```

---

```
void ex51(char *nome_ficheiro){
  char frase[100]; 
  printf("Introduza o texto que quer escrever neste ficheiro:\n"); 

  scanf("%100[^\n]",frase); // faz a leitura da linha

  FILE *fp=fopen(nome_ficheiro,"w");
  if(fp==NULL){
      printf("Error!!!\n");
  }else{ 
      fprintf(fp,"%s",frase); 
  }
 fclose(fp);
}
```

[**Exemplo**](https://goo.gl/ulDmc6)

Comment: Não resultou, continua a guardar só até eu dar um espaço ou enter.(ou seja guarda um carácter ou uma palavra)

Comment: @ppfernandes, deixei um link no final do código com o exemplo funcionando, de uma olhada e compare com o seu código, pode ser que tenha algum erro de lógica nele.

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgets` para ler uma linha. **Não use `gets`**, é motivo para demissão por justa causa.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ex51(char *nome_ficheiro)
{
   char frase[100];
   printf("Introduza o texto que quer escrever neste ficheiro:\n"); 

   if (fgets(frase, 100, stdin) == NULL)
   {
      printf("erro,nao foi possivel ler o texto");
     return;
   }

   FILE* fp=fopen(nome_ficheiro,"w");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!!!\n");
   }
   else
   {
      fprintf(fp,"%s",frase);
   }

   fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
   ex51("xxx");
}
```

Comment: fgets() faz com que o programa não chega a ler o texto(como no gets()) simplesmente passa a frente, mas eu vou tentar editar o programa de maneira a tirar o limite, e depois irei usar o fgets() para ver se já dá.